# Reason for keras validation zig-zagging

Tags: python, keras

I am training a NN and getting this result on loss and validation loss: 
[image: image 1]

These are 200 epochs, a batch size of 16, 500 training samples and 200 validation samples.

As you can see, after about 20 epochs, the validation loss begins to do a very exaggerated zig-zagging.

Do you know which could be the reason for that behavior?

I tried to increase the number of validation samples but that just increased the zig-zagging and made it more exaggerated.

Also, I added a decay value to the optimizer, but the loss and validation loss did not look so good.
[image: image 2]. 
I was looking for another way to improve it.

Any idea on which is the zig-zagging reason and how could I minimize it?

Answer (score 2):

This might be a case of **overfitting**:

> Overfitting refers to a model that models the “training data” too well. Overfitting happens when a model learns the detail and noise in the training data to the extent that it negatively impacts the performance of the model on new data [source](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-overfitting-846bf5b35e24).

Basically, you have a very small training sample (500), but are training for a very long time (200 epochs!).
The network will start learning your training data by heart and won't learn to generalise. It will thus seem to be very good during training, but will fail miserably on the test set.

[early stopping](https://machinelearningmastery.com/early-stopping-to-avoid-overtraining-neural-network-models/) is a nice way to avoid overfitting: basically, stop as soon as the validation loss becomes erratic/starts increasing. Another way to lower the chances of overfitting is to use techniques such as [*dropout*](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-for-regularizing-deep-neural-networks/) or simply to increase the training data.

**tldr;** you are overfitting. To avoid this issue, many possibilities: reduce drastically the number of epochs, use a dev set and a stopping criterion, have more training data, ...

For alternative explanations, see also [this question on QUORA](https://www.quora.com/What-could-be-explanations-for-validation-loss-zig-zagging-when-training-a-deep-neural-network).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that don't be worry for the zigzag fashion of the validation loss or validation accuracy. See, what happens when training of the neural network goes on, it makes the mistakes and update the weights, right ?( if you know the math behind it). So it is obvious that testing data will create zigzag because model is in training mode (learning stage). Once the model will get trained fully , you will notice that ... zigzag will decrease (if you have chose correct number of epochs).
So don't worry for this.